# How do I find "who" started my broswer via BrokerInfrastructure to show ads?

Tags: windows, windows-10, process, windows-services, dcom

**Abstract** -- I am trying to find out a "criminal" process that opens ads automatically when I am not using my Windows 10 PC. I tried Process Monitor but the Process trace ended at a system service called **Background Tasks Infrastructure Service**. I am asking for help on the next step to find out who started the ad via this service.

---

Long story short. I caught some virus (100% sure it was a virus) and did some clean-ups both manually and using Windows Defender (11/13/2016 late night). It seems, however, the virus was not completely cleared.

Something (cannot be so sure if this was the virus) spawns **Mozilla Firefox** (my default browser) once a day just to show the same web ad, which is here -- ad page, don't open since I am not sure if that page is safe: http://qaafa.com/7fKEs582d18c5aebf7euplsX1eWReAj?r=L2Rhb2xud29kL3p5eC5zcHBhc3dvZG5pd3phZC8vOnB0dGg=. This happened on 11/14/2016 for the first time. Today is 11/16, and it was indeed the third time this happened.

Since the parent process ID of that Firefox ends up pointing to nothing (this was my experience from the second time it happened which was yesterday), I used [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) to watch process creation events. Without filtering, the monitor captures thousands of events every second, so I filtered to include only process creation events that spawn "firefox.exe".

The good news was, it worked. The event was captured as

```
High Resolution Date & Time:    11/16/2016 6:41:00.6482030 PM
Event Class:    Process
Operation:  Process Create
Result: SUCCESS
Path:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe
TID:    8528
Duration:   0.0000000
PID:    904
Command line:   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -osint -url "http://dazwindowsapps.xyz/download/index.php?mn=9995"
```

And the details for the parent process who started Firefox was

```
Description:    Windows Explorer
Company:    Microsoft Corporation
Name:   explorer.exe
Version:    10.0.14393.0 (rs1_release.160715-1616)
Path:   C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe
Command Line:   C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe /factory,{75dff2b7-6936-4c06-a8bb-676a7b00b24b} -Embedding
PID:    7000
Parent PID: 812
Session ID: 1
User:   <hostname>\<username> (Personal user I am using)
Auth ID:    00000000:0008e4e4
Architecture:   64-bit
Virtualized:    False
Integrity:  Medium
Started:    11/16/2016 6:41:00 PM
Ended:  11/16/2016 6:42:00 PM
Modules:
...
```

The bad news, which was obvious, was that the parent process was "explorer.exe" and the path indicated it was actually the genuine **Windows Explorer** program and process.

The UUID **{75dff2b7-6936-4c06-a8bb-676a7b00b24b}** points to `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{75dff2b7-6936-4c06-a8bb-676a7b00b24b}`, which has a "LocalServer32" sub-key with "(Default)" value being `%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe /factory,{75dff2b7-6936-4c06-a8bb-676a7b00b24b}`.

However, the process information also gave that the parent ID of this specific instance of "explorer.exe" was 812, which is still running at the time I am back to my PC -- is the **BrokerInfrastructure (Background Tasks Infrastructure Service)**.

Now what I see is, this service is apparently a broker as is suggested by its name. There must be "some one" (a process, for example), published some event through this broker, and the broker spawned Windows Explorer itself with the command line to start Firefox. This event was likely to be (guessing) "I want to open this URL", and the genuine Windows service just chose my default broker for it.

---

Okay... **What is the next step** I should take to find out the actual "criminal" process?

---

**Additional information**

I actually not just had Process Monitor running, but also turned on "Audit process tracking" in **Local Group Policy**. Auditing shows the following "Process Creation" events occurred at that time (6:41:00pm):

1 --

```
Log Name:      Security
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing
Date:          11/16/2016 6:41:00 PM
Event ID:      4688
Task Category: Process Creation
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Audit Success
User:          N/A
Computer:      <hostname>
Description:
A new process has been created.

Creator Subject:
    Security ID:        SYSTEM
    Account Name:       <hostname>$
    Account Domain:     HOME
    Logon ID:       0x3E7

Target Subject:
    Security ID:        <hostname>\<username>
    Account Name:       <username>
    Account Domain:     <hostname>
    Logon ID:       0x8E4E4

Process Information:
    New Process ID:     0x27b0
    New Process Name:   C:\Windows\explorer.exe
    Token Elevation Type:   %%1938
    Mandatory Label:        Mandatory Label\Medium Mandatory Level
    Creator Process ID: 0x504
    Creator Process Name:   C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe
    Process Command Line:
```

2 --

```
Log Name:      Security
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing
Date:          11/16/2016 6:41:00 PM
Event ID:      4688
Task Category: Process Creation
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Audit Success
User:          N/A
Computer:      <hostname>
Description:
A new process has been created.

Creator Subject:
    Security ID:        SYSTEM
    Account Name:       <hostname>$
    Account Domain:     HOME
    Logon ID:       0x3E7

Target Subject:
    Security ID:        <hostname>\<username>
    Account Name:       <username>
    Account Domain:     <hostname>
    Logon ID:       0x8E4E4

Process Information:
    New Process ID:     0x1b58
    New Process Name:   C:\Windows\explorer.exe
    Token Elevation Type:   %%1938
    Mandatory Label:        Mandatory Label\Medium Mandatory Level
    Creator Process ID: 0x32c
    Creator Process Name:   C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe
    Process Command Line:
```

3 --

```
Log Name:      Security
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing
Date:          11/16/2016 6:41:00 PM
Event ID:      4688
Task Category: Process Creation
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Audit Success
User:          N/A
Computer:      <hostname>
Description:
A new process has been created.

Creator Subject:
    Security ID:        <hostname>\<username>
    Account Name:       <username>
    Account Domain:     <hostname>
    Logon ID:       0x8E4E4

Target Subject:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       -
    Account Domain:     -
    Logon ID:       0x0

Process Information:
    New Process ID:     0x388
    New Process Name:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe
    Token Elevation Type:   %%1938
    Mandatory Label:        Mandatory Label\Medium Mandatory Level
    Creator Process ID: 0x1b58
    Creator Process Name:   C:\Windows\explorer.exe
    Process Command Line:
```

Comment: If you get a virus, nuke the computer.  Reformat, restore from back up...

Comment: @Dave No backup. I would not reinstall if there's still hope. Actually this is not very urgent so I kind of want to figure out how to deal with these things in case I get to similar situation in the future.

Comment: For more clarity . You can get rid of a virus. Meaning the executable is removed. What you are unlikely to know is what else it did. For example let's say a virus is known for making the browser have a default search engine. Every time you load the browser you get the wrong engine and change it back to default. Until you remove the exe. Then it's fixed? What you don't know is it also made a change to files in the system. It also silently installed another exe which isn't designed to run for 2 months, which does something totally different but still evil.  You have no idea what the virus did.

Comment: Hence,  nuke the machine :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the service that runs scheduled tasks, did you check if there's not a scheduled task created to run daily that launches the url through explorer which would explain explorer passing it to the default browser? Sounds like the most likely culprit

Comment: You are excellent. Yes it was a scheduled task. I just sorted all tasks by "Last Run Time", and found one scheduled everyday at 6:41pm and executes exactly the same command shown there. It called itself "Adobe Up" so I ignored it when I was cleaning up scheduled tasks. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Consider marking it as the solution. ;)

Comment: @Seth I will when I double confirmed tomorrow it does not happen.

Comment: Glad to hear that you determined the root cause!  As I said earlier, the next time you encounter something of this nature you will find that performing a cleanup *"both manually and using Windows Defender"* probably isn't sufficient.  You really need to consider utilities that are designed to alleviate problems like this, such as RKill and Malwarebytes.

Comment: @Run5k I will try to be more careful. I was, actually, a few years ago. Just haven't used Windows very often these years, and forgot that the world is still evil.

Comment: @Seth Confirmed not happening today. Taken as solution.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, did you already try installing and running a Threat Scan using [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/)?  These days, that has really become a virus/malware "Troubleshooting 101" procedure.

Beyond that, quite frankly I am always rather meticulous when it comes to my Windows builds.  If I had one that was infected in that manner, I would ensure that I had a backup of my pertinent files and folder, then perform a full OS wipe & reload.  Utilities like Process Monitor, [RKill](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/rkill/) (which I typically run first), and Malwarebytes are terrific, but it is difficult to truly have peace of mind after an infection without reloading the OS.

Comment: This should be a comment as these are all relevant and good tips but don't answer the question asked at all.

Comment: @RonanThibaudau , I appreciate your feedback and you raise a good point.  It was simply a judgment call on my part.  Since the author emphasized that he was *"100% sure it was a virus""* and the problem was symptomatic of that infection, it was safe to assume that the leading malware detection software might be able to track down the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to stop it from happening, elsewhere:

Go to your Task Scheduler and disable/delete PPI Updater. This should stop it.